# What Modules in Haskell require a qualified import?

Tags: haskell, module

I know there are some modules where the functions overlap with Prelude or another standard Module.
Which ones are these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a potentially infinite number of such modules since there can be limitless numbers of packages each of which can supply limitless numbers of modules. The common ones you'll see around are in (I'm making this a wiki so others can edit):

- containers - The `Data.{Map,Set}` and other modules intentionally reuse many commonly-named operations.
- unordered-containers - The `Data.{HashMap,HashSet}` reuse many of the same function names such as `lookup`.

Comment: Some other notes: it is not an error to have two clashing names in scope, only when you try to use them. If a module exports only a handful of clashing names you can do `import ... hiding ...`. You don't actually need qualified imports to disambiguate calls, it's just more verbose, e.g. `Prelude.last` and `Data.ByteString.last`.